# virtual box 6.0.12 does not recognize usb device even guest addon is installed and extention pack

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have the problem:

virtual box 6.0.12 (Version 6.0.12 r133076 (Qt5.9.5)
) does not recognize usb device even guest addon is installed and extention pack

Host: ubuntu 18.04:
lsusb does show the usb devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualBox by default only supports USB 1.x devices.
You need the VirtualBox extension pack for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0,
and its version must match exactly that of VirtualBox.

For VirtualBox version 6.0.12, browse to
[VirtualBox extension pack 6.0.12](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.12/).

The two files you need to downlaod are:

- `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.12-133076.vbox-extpack`
- `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.12.vbox-extpack`.

Then in VirtualBox manager go to *File > Preferences > Extensions*,
click the add button on the right to add the two extension packs.

In order for VirtualBox to see your USB devices, your user must be in the `vboxusers`
group. Use this command:

```
sudo gpasswd -a yourusername vboxusers
```

Log out and back again for the change can take effect.

Now you can add a USB controller in Settings of the virtual machine.
Select USB on the left pane and choose USB 2.0 controller or USB 3.0 controller.
Only one type of controller is possible.

Next, insert the USB device to the host machine and click the add button to
add new USB filter.
Choose the USB device and Click OK.

For more details with screenshots see the article
[How to Access USB from VirtualBox Guest OS](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/access-usb-from-virtualbox-guest-os).

Comment: thanks a lot. adding the user to the vboxusers group solved it.

Comment: Hi, concerning the 2 downloads for extpack. I tried to install both, but vbox is saying they are installed, so looks like both are the same. only 1 ext pack to be checked in preferences..... you might want to check this? thank T

Comment: That's what the documentation said...

Comment: Life saver, thank you!